# How to effectively change the browser name of the WebDriver object?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I intend to perform some tests by using selenium with multiple web browsers. To distinguish between the different web drivers, I use the following line of code:

```
((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities().getBrowserName();
```

This will return a String indicating the web browser that is used by the `driver` object. However, for my Opera WebDriver object this will give me the String 'chrome'. I have tried changing this by explicitly setting the browser name to 'opera' using DesiredCapabilities:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setBrowserName("opera");
WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver(capabilities);
```

Unfortunately, this does not fix my problem. How do I effectively change the web browser name?

Comment: You can't do this. It is set the by the driver for specific browser and it can't be written to by your code. So you need some other way to store that info and call it back

Comment: I think @TarunLalwani is right

Comment: I will indeed have to store it in another way then. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please update the Question with your exact piece of code? I am interested at which stage you are exactly calling `getCapabilities().getBrowserName();`.

Comment: Also see Webdriver's Github and Issue 1459, [Method to change User Agent string](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues/1459).

Answer (score 1):

Your basic requirement is to identify browser initialization if I'm right, which can be done by getting user-agent from your browser using `JavascriptExecutor` as following:

```
String userAgent = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return navigator.userAgent;");

//following is for identifying opera browser initialization 
if(userAgent.contains("OPR/"){

  System.out.println("Browser currently in use is Opera");

}
```

Similarly you can identify other browser initilisation by referring [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) link

Comment: That's indeed my requirement. I already fixed the problem by storing the information elsewhere, yet tested your solution out of curiosity. It works but I think my present solution is more suitable. Thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately , you would not be able to change the BrowserName.

What instead you can try is to create function for specifically handling multiple browsers: -

```
package multiBrowser;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.opera.OperaDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;



public class MultiBrowserClass {
WebDriver driver;
@Test
@Parameters("browser")
public void multiBrowsers(String browserName) throws InterruptedException{
    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","D:\\My Work\\Setup\\JAR\\geckodriver.exe");
        ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();    
        FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);

    }
    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\My Work\\Setup\\JAR\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")){

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\My Work\\Setup\\JAR\\driver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }
    else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("opera")){

        System.setProperty("webdriver.opera.driver", "D:\\My Work\\Setup\\JAR\\driver\\operadriver.exe");
        driver = new OperaDriver(); 

    }

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.navigate().to("https://");

    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='navbar-main']/ul/li[5]/a")).click();    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='navbar-main']/ul/li[5]/ul/li/a")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("abc@mm.kk");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("1qaz2wsx");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='loginform']/div[8]/button")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Welcome abc@mm.kk")){
        System.out.println("User Successfully logged in");

    }else{
        System.out.println("Username or password you entered is incorrect");
    }

    driver.quit();

}

}
```

=======

Comment: Thank you for your reaction, but this does not answer my question. I already have functionality to initialise different WebDriver objects, I just wanted to be able to distinguish between them after they are initialised.